# Library netbeans Java

Tags: java

With this code I have I get an error: Package Hangman is missing. So I cannot use any Hangman import. Where can I find this?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import hangman.Hangman; // I have imported it here

public class Hangman {
    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
        Hangman hangman = new Hangman();

        System.out.println("************");
        System.out.println("* Hangman *");
        System.out.println("************");
        System.out.println("");
        printMenu();
        System.out.println("");

        while (hangman.gameOn()) {
            System.out.println(" Type a command: ");
            String command = reader.nextLine(); 
            if ( command.equals("quit")) {
                break;
            }

            System.out.println("Thank you for playing!");
        }
    }

    public static void printMenu() {
        System.out.println(" * menu *");
        System.out.println("quit   - quits the game");
        System.out.println("status  - prints the game status");
        System.out.println("a single letter uses the letter as a guess");
        System.out.println("an empty line prints this menu");    
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is your import? What's your project structure?

Answer (score 0):

You are most likely trying to import the class itself, that is, `Hangman`.

Change your code to the following and see if it works:

```
package hangman;  //Notice the change here. We are now declaring the package, not importing it.

import java.util.Scanner; 

public class Hangman {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
        Hangman hangman = new Hangman();

        System.out.println("************");
        System.out.println("* Hangman *");
        System.out.println("************");
        System.out.println("");
        printMenu();
        System.out.println("");

        while (hangman.gameOn()) {
            System.out.println(" Type a command: ");
            String command = reader.nextLine(); 
            if ( command.equals("quit")) {
                break;
            }

        System.out.println("Thank you for playing!");

        }
    }

    public static void printMenu() {
        System.out.println(" * menu *");
        System.out.println("quit   - quits the game");
        System.out.println("status  - prints the game status");
        System.out.println("a single letter uses the letter as a guess");
        System.out.println("an empty line prints this menu");

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ended up being missing project resources. Wanted to conclude this.